# Why does K2ZnO2 + H2SO4 yield K2SO4 + ZnSO4?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

$\ce{K2ZnO2 + 2H2SO4->ZnSO4 + K2SO4 + 2H2O}$

How does the ZnO2 ion disassemble here? Does it perform as a basic oxide, since we know that a basic oxide + an acid --> a salt + H2O?

I'm not sure, because a basic oxide does not carry a charge, and usually sports only a single oxygen atom.

When trying to write down this reaction on my own, I wrote it as

$\ce{K2ZnO2 + 2H2SO4->H2ZnO2 + K2SO4}$

It was a surprise for me when I looked up the answer.

Comment: Zinc oxide (or hydroxide) is amphoteric and behaves as such. With strong acids, it acts like a base, and vice versa.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - even if it is in the ionic form, and not as your 'average oxide' without charge?

Comment: You seem to already know what happens if zinc is in the anionic form. Look again at the reaction you wrote. This is right. Only it does not stop there.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - thank you! Maybe in the ionic form the oxide is even more basic. Or maybe there's no difference.

Comment: Of course the zincate anion is much more basic than zinc hydroxide. If you add a very weak acid (or a limited amount of a strong acid), you will end up with $\ce{Zn(OH)2}$.